# How to run pyannote.audio on cpu?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to run `pyannote` and getting error: "`CUDA out of memory`".

Because of that, I want to run my code on CPU rather than GPU.

```
from pyannote.audio import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline.from_pretrained("pyannote/speaker-diarization",use_auth_token="token...")

diarization = pipeline("example.wav")
```

How can I run the speaker-diarization pipeline on the CPU given the above configuration?

Answer (score 0):

you can use torch

```
from pyannote.audio import Pipeline
import torch

pipeline = Pipeline.from_pretrained("pyannote/speaker-diarization",use_auth_token="token...")
device = torch.device("cpu")
pipeline.to(device)
diarization = pipeline("example.wav")
```